# XML structuring and multiple xml based on data algorithm

Tags: c#, xml, algorithm

This is my table:

ItemsTable
Id, Codes, Price, Weight

[image: ItemsTable]

I want to produce one or many xml files based on these rules using C#.

Within the xml there can not be more than 99 items, if it is more it should start a new xml file. There can not be more than 99 items in MyItems, if there are more it should start a new MyCollection.

```
<xml>
 <MyCollections>
 <!--- 0 to 99 MyCollection items allowed-->
  <MyCollection>
   <Code>6201110000</Code>
   <MyItems>
     <!--- 0 to 99 MyItems allowed -->
     <MyItem>
        <Sequence>1</Price>
        <Price>10</Price>
        <Weight>20</Weight>
     </MyItem>

     ....

     <MyItem>
        <Sequence>99</Price>
        <Price>300</Price>
        <Weight>2</Weight>
     </MyItem>
  </Item>
</MyCollection>

<MyCollection>
 <Code>6201110000</Code>
  <MyItems>     
    <MyItem>
        <Sequence>100</Price>
        <Price>10</Price>
        <Weight>20</Weight>
    </MyItem>
    .....

</MyCollection>
```

Comment: So have you tried anything yourself so far? You've outlined requirements but haven't described an actual problem you've run into while trying to implement this.

Comment: "_I want to produce one or many xml files based on these rules using C#._" Is your question whether we want to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loops is complicated.  I think I got it right.  I used Xml Linq.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string PATH = @"c:\temp\";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Codes", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Columns.Add("Weight", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", "620111000", 1.00, 20 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2", "610433000", 4.00, 30 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "3", "620111005", 7.00, 50 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "4", "620111006", 6.00, 60 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "5", "620111006", 5.00, 70 });

            string xml = "<xml><MyCollections></MyCollections></xml>";

            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>("Codes")).GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Codes")).ToList();


            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XElement myCollections = doc.Descendants("MyCollections").FirstOrDefault();

            int sequence = 0;
            int file_count = 1;
            XElement myCollection = null;
            XElement myItems = null;
            string firstGroupName = "";
            string code = "";

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                code = group.Key;
                //only add here if there is not 99 items in file
                //other wise it will be added later
                if (sequence < 99)
                {
                    myCollection = new XElement("MyCollection", new XElement("Code", code));
                    myCollections.Add(myCollection);
                    myItems = new XElement("MyItems");
                    myCollection.Add(myItems);

                    firstGroupName = group.Key;
                }

                foreach (DataRow row in group)
                {
                    sequence++;
                    if (sequence > 99)
                    {
                        if (firstGroupName == code)
                        {
                            doc.Save(PATH + code + "_" + file_count.ToString() + ".xml");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            doc.Save(PATH + firstGroupName + "_" + code + "_" + file_count.ToString() + ".xml");
                        }
                        file_count++;

                        sequence = 1;
                        doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
                        myCollections = doc.Descendants("MyCollections").FirstOrDefault();

                        myCollection = new XElement("MyCollection", new XElement("Code", code));
                        myCollections.Add(myCollection);
                        myItems = new XElement("MyItems");
                        myCollection.Add(myItems);
                    }

                    XElement myItem = new XElement("MyItem", new object[] {
                        new XElement("Sequence", sequence),
                        new XElement("Price", row.Field<decimal>("Price")),
                        new XElement("Weight", row.Field<int>("Weight"))
                    });
                    myItems.Add(myItem);
                }
            }
            if (myItems.Elements("MyItem") != null)
            {
                if (firstGroupName == code)
                {
                    doc.Save(PATH + code + "_" + file_count.ToString() + ".xml");
                }
                else
                {
                    doc.Save(PATH + firstGroupName + "_" + code + "_" + file_count.ToString() + ".xml");
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query your table with take ans skip.

Let's say you have two methods:

```
    private IList<string> Query(string s)
    {
        // Execute your SQL query 
    }

    private void SerializeItems(IList<object> itemsList)
    {
        //Serialize your itemslist to an xml file
    }
```

You can read 99 item and serialize them:

```
    var offset = 99;
    var readMore = true;

    while (readMore)
    {
        var itemsList = Query(
            $@"SELECT ... FROM ... OFFSET {offset} ROWS FETCH NEXT 99 ROWS ONLY;");

        SerializeItems(itemsList);

        offset += 99;
        readMore = itemsList.Count == 99;
    }
```